# NestJS Set AccessToken in an HttpOnly Cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, nestjs

I am implementing JWT in NestJS + Angular but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Here is my endpoint:

```
@Post('sign-up')
  async signUp(
    @Body() data: SignUpModelInterface,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response
  ): Promise<void> {
    const token: string = await this.authService.signUp(data);

    response.cookie('access-token', token, { httpOnly: true });
  }
```

Is that the correct way to create a new user and set the access token in the response? You can also see that I am not returning any value from the endpoint (i.e., `Promise<void>`) but again I am not sure if it is the correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest returning *something* even just a simple `{ success: true }` or similar, to make it easier to say that it ended, even just a `return` statement, to make the flow of code more apparent, but this would be fine for setting the `access-token` cookie as an HttpOnly cookie